# css for checked checkbox

Tags: php, html, css

I want to display the checkbox in while loop and nned to apply the CSS based on `$status` value.If status=open in database open should be checked and vice versa for `status='Close'` .I have CSS for each and every row based on id.I created random id in PHP variable `$a`.

Now This is working only for `status='open'` which is checked in if condition.

```
     $a=0;
         while($sfet=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
         {
              echo ('<style>

      .ck-button'.$a.' {
       margin:0px;
       background-color:#EFEFEF;
       border-radius:4px;
      border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
      overflow:auto;
       float:left;
       }

    .ck-button'.$a.' #label'.$a.' {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
    }
    .ck-button'.$a.' #label'.$a.' #span'.$a.' {
     text-align:center;
     padding:3px 0px;
      display:block; 
     border-radius:4px;
      }

    .ck-button'.$a.' #label'.$a.' input {
     position:absolute;
     top:-20px;
     }
    input#o1'.$a.':checked + #span'.$a.' {
    background-color: green;
     color: #fff;
   }
  input#o2'.$a.':checked + #span'.$a.' {
   background-color: red;
  color: #fff; 
   }
  input#o3'.$a.':checked + #span'.$a.' {
  background-color: orange;
   color: #fff;
   }

 .ck-button'.$a.' #label'.$a.':hover #o1'.$a.' + #span'.$a.' {
 background-color:green;
 }
 .ck-button'.$a.' #label'.$a.':hover #o2'.$a.' + #span'.$a.' {
  background-color:red;  
 }
 .ck-button'.$a.' #label'.$a.':hover #o3'.$a.' + #span'.$a.' {
  background-color:orange;
  }
   </style>'); 
           $title=$sfet['title'];
           $c_name=$sfet['c_name'];
           $e_first_name=$sfet['e_first_name'];
           $status=$sfet['status'];
           $req_id=$sfet['req_id'];
           $e_id=$sfet['e_id'];
           echo '<tr><td><a href="broadcast_detail.php?req_id='.$req_id.'" class="astext">'.$title.'</a></td><td>'.$c_name.'</td><td>'.$e_first_name.'</td>';
            $count="select * from resume where e_id='$e_id' and req_id='$req_id'";
            $count1=mysql_query($count);
            $num=mysql_num_rows($count1);
           echo '<td>'.$num.'</td>';
           if($status=='Open')
           {
           echo"<td><div class='ck-button".$a."'><label id='label".$a."'><input type='radio' name='sta_choice".$a."' id='o1".$a."' onclick=demo('Open',".$req_id."); value='Open' checked><span id='span".$a."'>Open</span></label></div>";
            echo"<div class='ck-button".$a."'><label id='label".$a."'><input type='radio' name='sta_choice".$a."' id='o2".$a."' value='Close' onclick=demo('Close',".$req_id.");><span id='span".$a."'>Close</span></label></div>";
             echo"<div class='ck-button".$a."'><label id='label".$a."'><input type='radio' name='sta_choice".$a."' id='o3".$a."' value='Hold' onclick=demo('Hold',".$req_id.");><span id='span".$a."'>Hold</span></label></div></td><br><br>";

           }
           else if($status=='close'){


             echo"<td><div class='ck-button".$a."'><label id='label".$a."'><input type='radio' name='sta_choice".$a."' id='o1".$a."' onclick=demo('Open',".$req_id."); value='Open'><span id='span".$a."'>Open</span></label></div>";
              echo"<div class='ck-button".$a."'><label id='label".$a."'><input type='radio' name='sta_choice".$a."' id='o2".$a."' value='Close' onclick=demo('Close',".$req_id.");><span id='span".$a."' checked>Close</span></label></div>";
               echo"<div class='ck-button".$a."'><label id='label".$a."'><input type='radio' name='sta_choice".$a."' id='o3".$a."' value='Hold' onclick=demo('Hold',".$req_id.");><span id='span".$a."'>Hold</span></label></div></td><br><br>";

           }
  $a++;
  }
```

Comment: You have said that the status is "closed" but in your code you are checking for "close". Could be this the problem?

Comment: status='Close' not closed

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the if statement is faulty, it echo's the exact same thing, thus not resulting in any changes if the database option changes.

Also Open is with a capital letter, and close is not.

Comment: I typed the Close  as close.but C is in uppercase in my code

Comment: You could remove the else if and make it else to make your code shorter. if it's not Open, and there is only two options, it has to be closed.

Comment: I have one more option 'Hold'